# Show that $\| \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} \|_{2}^{2} < \| \mathbf{b}\|_{2}^{2}$ given $|x_{i}| = 1 \quad \forall i$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, upper-lower-bounds, constraints

Suppose that I solve the following optimization problem:

$$ \underset{\mathbf{x}}{\text{minimize}} \quad || \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} ||_{2}^{2} $$
$$ \text{subject to} \; \; |x_{i}| = 1 \quad \forall i $$

where $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times 1}$ with $|\mathbf{b}|_{i} \in \{-1, 0, 1, N \}$, $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N}$ is a **lower triangular Toeplitz matrix** with $|\mathbf{A}|_{i,j} \leq 1$, and $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}$ and $M > N$.

Can I ever be sure that:

$$\| \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{\ast} \|_{2}^{2} < \| \mathbf{b}\|_{2}^{2}$$

where $\mathbf{x}_{\ast}$ is the optimal solution?

If so, how can I show this? Or perhaps in other words, what are the conditions that allow me to say this?

---

Subtracting and expanding this out, we get:

$$ \|\mathbf{b}\|_{2}^{2} - 2 \mathbf{b}^{H} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{\ast} + \mathbf{x}_{\ast}^{H} \mathbf{A}^{H} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{\ast} -  \|\mathbf{b}\|_{2}^{2} < 0 $$

ie that:

$$ \mathbf{x}_{\ast}^{H} \mathbf{A}^{H} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{\ast}  < 2 \mathbf{b}^{H} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{\ast} $$

But I don't see how that actually tells me anything.

### Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is an idea. Since $|x_{i}| = 1$, if we transpose and then  take absolute values, we get:

$$ \mathbf{1}^{T} \mathbf{A}^{H} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{1} < 2 \mathbf{1}^{T} | \mathbf{A}^{H} \mathbf{b}| $$

Does that spark any ideas? Hmm...**I think the restrictions on the absolute values of the elements will be important here**...but I can't figure out how they fit together...

---

Edit:

The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is a causal FIR filter matrix -- ie lower triangular and Toeplitz. See: https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Matrix_Filter_Representations.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.  For instance, consider 
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&0\\1&0}, \quad b = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}.
$$
In this case, we find that all $\|b - Ax\|_2^2 = 2$ for all $x$ satisfying $|x_1| = 1$, but $\|b\|_2^2 = 1$.

Comment: Okay let me add a restriction I forgot...Sorry!!

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: Okay, thank you! This reminds me, actually we have $|b_{i}| \in \{-1, 0, 1, N\} $ ie there exists $b_{i}$ such that at least one of them is equal to -1, another to 0, another to 1, and another to N. Thank you for helping me be more clear.